# Converting chinese to pinyin

Tags: parsing, cjk

I've found places on the web such as http://www.chinesetopinyin.com that convert Chinese characters to pinyin (romanization).

Does anyone know how to do this, or have a database that can be parsed?

---

EDIT: I'm using C# but would actually prefer a database/flatfile.

Answer (score 6):

possible solution using [Python](http://python.org/):

I think that Unicode database contains pinyin romanizations for chinese characters, but these are not included in `unicodedata` module data.

however, you can use some external libraries, like [cjklib](http://code.google.com/p/cjklib/), example:

```
# coding: UTF-8
import cjklib
from cjklib.characterlookup import CharacterLookup

c = u'好'

cjk = CharacterLookup('T')
readings = cjk.getReadingForCharacter(c, 'Pinyin')
for r in readings:
    print r
```

output:

```
hāo
hǎo
hào
```

**UPDATE**

cjklib comes with an standalone `cjknife` utility, which micht help. some usage is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/cjklib/wiki/Screenshots)

Comment: .. and if you want ascii-only or numeric representation, you may find how to do it in documentation, or you can pick the first pinyin and remove the accents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string

Comment: Unicode does have a table for Character to Pinyin mapping, it's called Unihan and has loads of data. :)

Comment: `raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8` any idea ?

Comment: jokoon: i don't know.. what are you getting from `import locale; locale.getlocale()`?