# How to get Ruby 1.9 regexp supports \p{Nonspacing_Mark}?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

Isn't the diacritical mark above "a" should be removed by the Regex?

```
 "hǎo".gsub(/\p{Nonspacing_Mark}/, '')
 => "hǎo" 

 "hǎo".gsub(/\p{Mn}/, '')
 => "hǎo"
```

**Update:**

I kind of get it from how it works in Java.

```
Normalizer.normalize("hǎo", Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{Mn}+", "")
```

I need to normalizer it first to split the "ǎ" into "a" and the diacritical mark.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571480/converting-chinese-to-pinyin

Comment: Does Ruby know your source code  is in UTF-8?

Comment: Are you wanting to this wickedness because you don’t know how to compare two strings in an “accent-insensitive” fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puts UnicodeUtils.nfkd("ﻺ (hǎo)").gsub(/[\p{Nonspacing_Mark}]/, '')
```

See [How to replace the Unicode gem on Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322856/how-to-replace-the-unicode-gem-on-ruby-1-9)